Highlight selected interval in Observable Vegalite
I am creating a graph where the user can select an interval on the graph and the part will be different color than the other parts on the graph. The following is part of the code for creating the graph
const selectedInterval = vl.selectInterval('selected_interval')
  .encodings("x"); // added the x-encoding to constrain selection

const companySelection = vl.selectPoint()
  .fields('Company')
  .bind({Company: vl.menu(full_companyName).name("Company: ")});

const linePlot = vl.markLine()
  .data(data_full)
  .params(companySelection, selectedInterval)
  .title({text: "Revenue of partner companies",
          subtitle: "Click to select interval"})
  .transform(
    vl.filter(companySelection)
  )
  .encode(
    vl.x().fieldT('Year/Month').timeUnit('yearmonth').title('Month/Year'),
    vl.y().fieldQ(fullDataFactor).title(fullDataFactor),
    vl.color().if(selectedInterval, vl.fieldN('Company')).value("gray").title('Company'),
    vl.opacity().if(selectedInterval, vl.value(0.7)).value(0.1)
  );

This code works well for a scatter plot, the selected interval will remain the same color while the other turns gray and have a lower opacity. However, in my line graph, when I selected the interval, everything becomes the same.
There is another interesting thing, when the very left of the line is selected, the whole line will go back to the original color, but if the very left of the line isn't selected it is still gray.
How can I modify this code to allow only the selected interval to stay its original color while all the other part turn gray and decrease in its opacity?
I tried creating two layers of markLine, one for the selected and the other for the non-selected, but there are no graphs when I tried to run the code.
const selectedInterval = vl.selectInterval('selected_interval')
  .encodings("x"); // constrain selection to x-axis

const companySelection = vl.selectPoint()
  .fields('Company')
  .bind({Company: vl.menu(full_companyName).name("Company: ")});

// Layer for non-selected intervals (gray and transparent)
const nonSelectedLayer = vl.markLine()
  .data(data_full)
  .params(companySelection, selectedInterval)
  .transform(
    vl.filter(companySelection),
    vl.filter(vl.not(selectedInterval))
  )
  .encode(
    vl.x().fieldT('Year/Month').timeUnit('yearmonth').title('Month/Year'),
    vl.y().fieldQ(fullDataFactor).title(fullDataFactor),
    vl.color().value('gray').title('Company'),
    vl.opacity().value(0.1)
  );

// Layer for selected intervals (original color)
const selectedLayer = vl.markLine()
  .data(data_full)
  .params(companySelection, selectedInterval)
  .transform(
    vl.filter(companySelection),
    vl.filter(selectedInterval)
  )
  .encode(
    vl.x().fieldT('Year/Month').timeUnit('yearmonth').title('Month/Year'),
    vl.y().fieldQ(fullDataFactor).title(fullDataFactor),
    vl.color().fieldN('Company').title('Company'),
    vl.opacity().value(1)
  );

// Combine layers
return vl.layer(nonSelectedLayer, selectedLayer)
  .title({
    text: "Revenue of Partner Companies",
    subtitle: "Click to select interval"
  });


